# Using math.random to generate a certain amount of random numbers in java

Tags: java, random

I need help making a program in java that lets you write a number in textField and then generate that amount of random numbers from 0-9 using i = (int) (Math.random() * 10.0). For example if I would write 5 in the textField the program would generate 5 random numbers from 0-9.

Thanks

Comment: Java != JavaScript - please clarify your chosen language - then read our [ask] page to improve your question

Comment: have you done something yet?

Comment: 1. This question is too simple. 2. Java or javaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since you want to use the Math.random() method try the following:

```
    int times = 5;//how many numbers to output

    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        System.out.println((int)(Math.random()*10));
        //you must cast the output of Math.random() to int since it returns double values
    }
```

I multiplied by 10 because Math.random() returns a value greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Comment: Change your loop to `i < times` -- you are now printing 6 numbers

Comment: I just gave an example value to times i never said it will print five numbers.
Anyway,i changed it to prevent future confusion thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new Java 8 streams API:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(myTextField.getText());
int[] random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 10).limit(n).toArray();
```

- uses the current thread local random (recommended over creating a new `Random` instance)
- creates a random stream of integers in the range [0..10) -> 0..9
- Stream terminates after n numbers have been generated
- the stream result is collected and returned as an array

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = value entered in textfield;
int generatedRandomNumber = 0;
java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
for(int i=0 ; i<x ; i++) {
    generatedRandomNumber=rand.nextInt(10);//here you have your random number, do whatever you want....
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation - it will make your code easier to read. Also, don't make your lines longer than 80 columns - just put the comment on another line